# Reshape with dplyr and stubs

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

```
DATA=data.frame(    STUDENT =c(1, 2, 3),    
                 GRADE1 =c(7, 3, NA),   
                 GRADE2 =c(6, 5, 9),    
                 GRADE3 =c(4, NA, 2),   
                 GYM1   =c(2, 0, NA),   
                 GYM2   =c(9, 7, 7),    
                 GYM3   =c(1, NA, 6))   

DATAWANT = data.frame(  STUDENT =c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),    
                       TIME =c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3),    
                       GRADE    =c(7, 6, 4, 3, 5, 9, 2),    
                       GYM  =c(2, 9, 1, 0, 7, 7, 6))
```

I have DATA and wish to create DATAWANT by shaping wide to long and taking STUBS (GRADE, GYM) as the columns and the values as the cell values. My attempt, doesn't work

```
library(tidyr)

DATAWANT.TRY=pivot_longer(DATA, 
                    cols = -c(STUDENT), 
                    names_to = c('GRADE', 'GYM'), 
                    names_pattern = '(.*?)_([A-Z])_Grade(\\d+)', 
                    values_to = 'Score')
```

Comment: You use `names_to = c('CLASS', 'GRADE')` but `CLASS` doesn't exist in `DATAWANT`, can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.value` in `names_to`:

```r
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(DATA, 
             cols = -c(STUDENT), 
             names_to = c('.value', 'TIME'), 
             names_pattern = '(.*)(\\d+)', 
             values_to = 'Score',
             values_drop_na = TRUE)

#   STUDENT TIME  GRADE   GYM
# 1       1 1         7     2
# 2       1 2         6     9
# 3       1 3         4     1
# 4       2 1         3     0
# 5       2 2         5     7
# 6       3 2         9     7
# 7       3 3         2     6
```

---

**Explanation:**

You should define the pattern of existing columns in `names_pattern`. In this case, your column names can be defined in two groups. One group is the first part of the column name; either `GRADE` or `GYM`. The other is the digit. You should use regex to define those:

```
(.*)(\d+)
```

This will match every column with digits. You could be more specific and use e.g. `(GRADE|GYM)(\d+)`. The parentheses are meant to capture groups.  In `names_to` element, you define the names of the new columns.

In `names_to`, where you define new column names, `.value` refers to:

> ".value" indicates that the corresponding component of the column name
> defines the name of the output column containing the cell values,
> overriding values_to entirely.

Here, `.value` refers to whatever matches `(.*)`, until the first digits, so both `GRADE` and `GYM`.